# Understanding the loss of orthogonality of Classical Gram-Schmidt Procedure

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices

I am having a hard time understanding the "loss of orthogonality" of classical Gram Schmidt procedure (CGSP) and how the Modified Gram Schmidt procedure (MGSP) resolves this issue.

The following two pseudocodes are for CGSP and MGSP :
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}
$\textbf{function[Q,R]=CGSP(A)}\\
{\bf for~} j=0, \ldots, n-1   \\
~~~  a_j^\perp :=  a_j  \\
~~~ {\bf for~}  k=0, \dots, j-1  \\
~~~ ~~~ \rho_{k,j} := q_k^H a_j^\perp  \\
~~~ ~~~ a_j^\perp := a_j^\perp - \rho_{k,j} q_k   \\
~~~ {\bf end} \\
~~~ \rho_{j,j} := \| {a}_j^\perp \|_2  \\
~~~  q_j := a_j^\perp / \rho_{j,j}   \\
{\bf end}
\end{array}
&\qquad\qquad
\begin{array}
$\textbf{function[Q,R]=MGSP(A)}\\
{\bf for~}  j=0, \ldots, n-1  \\
~~\\
~~~ {\bf for~}  k=0, \dots, j-1  \\
~~~ ~~~ \rho_{k,j} := a_k^H a_j  \\
~~~ ~~~ a_j := a_j - \rho_{k,j} a_k  \\
~~~ {\bf end} \\
~~~ \rho_{j,j} := \| {a}_j \|_2  \\
~~~ a_j := a_j / \rho_{j,j} \\
{\bf end}
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}

On MATLAB, I tried to consider a large matrix of size $100\times 100$ and performed QR decomposition using CGSP, after which I computed $\|I-QQ^{T}\|_{2}$ and received a value of $1.991\times10^{-1}$ which unlike the MGSP gave me a value of $2.012\times10^{-15}$. Therefore, I wish to understand the following :

> 1. Geometrically, how is there a loss of orthogonality of $q$ when we project the $k^{th}$ column vector $a$ onto all previous $k-1$ vectors? That is to say why does this type of loss exist geometrically?
> 2. How does MGSP resolve this issue? From the algorithm above for MGSP in what line does it really solves this issue of loss of orthogonality?

Comment: What does $H$ mean in the first line of the second for loop?

Comment: The H represents the hermitian of a matrix since we are assuming the matrix in general lies in complex space. Eventhough it shouldn't make a difference if H was replaced by a transpose and assumed A was real. @Raskolnikov

Comment: OK, another point: how is $q$ initialised in the CGSP algorithm? I suppose it's left out to keep the pseudocode compact.

Comment: I believe both R and Q are initialized to be equal to the zero vector of size n after which we perform the necessary allocations at each iteration @Raskolnikov

Comment: [After reading this](https://www.math.uci.edu/~ttrogdon/105A/html/Lecture23.html), I understand that you won't see any loss of orthogonality if you look at it purely geometrically. The point is that the loss arises from numerical instability of the first algorithm. In a perfect geometrical world, this doesn't happen. But in computer arithmetics, it does.

Comment: Is it because when we are finding $a_{j}^{\perp}$ we are subtracting $a_{j}$ from all j-1 previous terms which creates a numerical error in addition of j-1 terms? Especially if we are projecting a vector onto 100 terms and then performing a subtraction operation @Raskolnikov

Comment: I don't think that's the right way to summarize the problem. We perform just as much many arithmetic operations in either method. The difference is if an error is introduced when computing $q_2$ such that $q_1 \cdot q_2 \approx e > 0$ then that non-orthogonality could mean you might double-subtract that error when computing $q_3$ (and so on). Here is where MGSP makes a difference. The link @Raskolnikov pasted really works through an example of this. You can see this geometrically if you intentionally introduce an error when computing $q_2$ and see how that effects $q_3$.